# Immutability removing key from object by destructuring

Tags: javascript, babeljs, immutability, ecmascript-next

I have an object with a simplified structure like so:

```
state = {
  todo: {
    1: {text: 'Buy apples'},
    2: {text: 'Buy milk'}
  }
}
```

If I wanted to remove a todo item immutability, according to other answers on Stack Overflow I could destructure the todo's list:

```
const idToDelete = 2

let {
  [idToDelete]: deleted,
  ...newTodo
} = state.todo
```

If I do `console.log(newTodo)`, then it has the same value of `state.todo`, meaning that it hasn't removed to todo item with id of 2. If I  `console.log(deleted)` then it returns the contents of the todo I want to delete: `{text: 'Buy milk'}`.

I'm aware that it would be somewhat easier to manage this using a library  such as Immutable.js, however I would like to know why destructuring the object does not remove the todo item. Thanks.

Comment: In general, remember that all object property names in JavaScript are strings, and using values other than strings will sometimes yield unexpected results. In this case, however, you've run into a known bug in Babel: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/4196 Using a string instead of a number will fix the issue, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need stage-0 to achieve what do you want. If you check my code you will see that if you use a string to destruct the params it will works as you expect but if you use a number variable, the result will be the full object. I guess this should be a bug in the implementation.

```js
const state = {
  todo: {
    1: {text: 'Buy apples'},
    2: {text: 'Buy milk'}
  }
}
const id = 1
const { [id]: deleted, ...newTodo } = state.todo

console.log(deleted)
console.log(newTodo)

/********* GOOD EXAMPLE *********/

const { [id.toString()]: del, ...goodNewTodo } = state.todo

console.log(del)
console.log(goodNewTodo)
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a difference in how this handles string keys versus number keys. To my way of thinking, this doesn't seem proper, so I wonder if there is a bug somewhere.

```js
const orig = {
  a:1,
  b:2,
  1:'a',
  2:'b'
};

const {2:val_for_2, ...rest_for_2} = orig;
const {b:val_for_b, ...rest_for_b} = orig;

console.log('val_for_2:', val_for_2);
console.log('rest_for_2:', rest_for_2);
console.log('val_for_b:', val_for_b);
console.log('rest_for_b:', rest_for_b);

// output (as of late Feb, 2017):
// val_for_2: b
// rest_for_2: {
//   "1": "a",
//   "2": "b",
//   "a": 1,
//   "b": 2
// }
// val_for_b: 2
// rest_for_b: {
//   "1": "a",
//   "2": "b",
//   "a": 1
// }
```